# Android: Specifying a onClick() member method in XML?

Tags: java, android

I have a layout in XML as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:onClick="myButton.performClick" />
```

myButton is a member of this activity, is it possible use a class member method here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick) say (emphasis mine):

> you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) **method of your context**
>   (typically, your Activity)

If you wanted to execute a method on a field, you could wrap it I suppose.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="performClick" />
```

Then:

```
public void performClick(View view) {
    myButton.performClick(view);
}
```

but that almost defeats the purpose of the XML `onClick` attribute (making things more concise). Is there a good reason for `performClick` to be on your button instead of your activity anyway?

Lastly, doing this on the LinearLayout is fine. The attribute is supported for all [Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick).

Comment: I have a button inside a layout for formatting purposes, a click anywhere in the layout should trigger the button as well.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible use a class member method here?

According to the API - no. The [API says](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick):

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View.

Answer (score 0):

onClick doesn't go in the Linear Layout tag. It goes in the tag of the button whose on click you want to set.

So you do it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

  <Button
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:onClick="methodName"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But it's valid to set an onClick for a layout right? Basically what I'm getting at, can I specify a method on a class member in onClick in XML? Is there some way to do android:onClick="someMember.methodName" ?